# generate temporary file to replace real file

Tags: python-3.x, atomic, temporary-files

I need to generate a temporary file to replace a system file with new contents.

I have the code, and it works, but I was thinking if there is some module that automatically does that, along the lines of:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFileFor('/etc/systemfile', delete=False) as fp:
    ...
```

This would create a temporary file with the same permissions and owner of the original file and in the same folder. Then I would write my new contents and atomically replace the original systemfile with the new one. Heck, the context manager could do the replacement for me when the file is closed!

My current code is:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, dir='/etc') as fp:
    tempfilename = fp.name
    fp.write('my new contents')

orig_stat = os.stat('/etc/systemfile')
os.chown(tempfilename, orig_stat.st_uid, orig_stat.st_gid)
os.chmod(tempfilename, orig_stat.st_mode)

os.replace(tempfilename, '/etc/systemfile')
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such context manager in tempfile but it's not too difficult to write your own context manager:

```
class NamedTemporaryFileFor(object):
    def __init__(self, orig_path, delete=True, dir=None):
        self.orig_path = orig_path
        self.named_temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=delete, dir=dir)

    def __enter__(self):
        self.named_temp_file.__enter__()
        return self

    def write(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.named_temp_file.write(*args, **kwargs)

    def __exit__(self, exc, value, tb):
        orig_stat = os.stat(self.orig_path)
        os.chown(self.named_temp_file.name, orig_stat.st_uid, orig_stat.st_gid)
        os.chmod(self.named_temp_file.name, orig_stat.st_mode)

        self.named_temp_file.__exit__(exc, value, tb)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with NamedTemporaryFileFor(sys.argv[1], delete=False, dir="/etc") as fp:
        f.write(b'my new content')
```

(Note that I've had to pass a byte string to the `write` method to make the example work)